# cordova hybrid app build fail with vs2013 up2 (chinese traditional)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cordova, utf-8, visual-studio-cordova

I build cordova project with vs2013 up2 for windows phone platform and receive some error as follow , but build for ios & android is ok .

(1)Non-whitespace before first tag.

I found the js file  `"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\util\xml-helpers.js"`  in line 124 command

```
var contents = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf-8').replace("\ufeff", "");
```

...is failing in chinese traditional environment, when building for windows phone platform the WMAppManifest.xml file has BOM code , so will be error as `嚙踝蕭??xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, it should be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

have any idea can fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are seeing (issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5477) was fixed in Cordova 3.5

(I'm a new poster and haven't earned the reputation points to include more than 2 links in my response, so I'm saving those for the ones that matter below).

If you update to the latest CTP 2.0 for Multi-Device Hybrid Apps, you will pick up the fix.

Unfortunately, there is an other Cordova issue that still exists in version 3.5 which also impacts WP8 in localized environments (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6932).
It has been fixed in Cordova version 3.6 which hasn't yet been released, but here's how you can pick up the fix.

After installing the new MDD tools, create an MDD project and build for WP8.  (It will fail under Chinese as it did before.)

Now go into `c:\Users\<username>\cordova\lib\wp\cordova\3.5.0\wp8\bin`

Replace the existing create.js with the version from here 
(click "Raw" to view just the file contents)

https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-wp8/blob/ac097f2801d4defe5e4d445e10b7102001631a54/wp8/bin/create.js

Create a new project and build again for wp8.  It should work now and future projects should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked by removing android and adding again.

remove:

```
ionic platform rm android
```

add:

```
ionic platform add android
```

You can execute these commands at your project directory.